# Menus show up as transparent

Tags: html, css, javascript

Can someone help me figure out why my pull down menus (buildings, BV Mail) are showing up as being transparent on some of the pages and not the others.

The address is www.bv340.com.

Let me know if I can provide any more information.

Also, it doesn't seem to matter what browser, they all do the same thing.

Comment: We'll need to see some code to help you figure this out

Comment: Looks like a z-index problem, but can't be sure without code

Comment: Don't have time for a better answer, but can you add a high z-index to your menu item UL's and LI's??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't believe they are showing up as semi-transparent.

This is an issue with your `z-index` on the menu

Try adding the following to `#p7menubar li ul`:

```
#p7menubar li ul {
    z-index: 1;
}
```